# How to add 7 lines for address in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I need to have 7 lines for address in moderncvv. I am using classic style.

Comment: Since that involves redefining a bunch of macros and commands, could you explain what you need to put in these 7 lines?

Comment: Please add the code you use (delete personal information of course or write `name` for name etc.) and please show us (adding with a comment sign) were you want the 7 lines with which content.  You one line question gives not enouph information for a good answer, I think.

Comment: Are you still interested in receiving an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `\Longstack` (`stackengine` package) for the address.

EDITED for `classic` style the OP had originally requested.  In my MWE, I right-align the stack.  I had to manually set the interline spacing with `\setstackgap{L}{}`, since the style redefined `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{geometry}

\firstname{\textsc{J}} % Your first name
\familyname{\textsc{D}} % Your last name


\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\address{%
  \Longstack[r]{John Doe\\Professor of Engineering\\ 
                University of Anonymous\\ M.E. Dept.\\
                Building 893\\ Mail Stop 8354\\ Anytown, AK}}{USA}
\mobile{(+00 000) 0000}
\phone{(+00 00) 0000}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{abc@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]